# Count lines after line with specific character

Tags: python

I have a file which contains this data:

```
>P136
FCF#0.73
FCF#0.66
FCF#0.86
>P129
FCF#0.72
>P142
>P144
>P134
FCF#0.70
FCF#0.82
```

And I need to count the number of lines after a line containing ">" , but keeping the ">" line as reference, for this example the output should be:

```
>P136 3
>P129 1
>P134 2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Question: when you say 'line containing ">"', can the ">" potentially be somewhere other than at the beginning of the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dictionary to store the count per line, and every time there is no `>` at the start, increment the count:

```
counts = {}
current = None

with open(filename) as fo:
   for line in fo:
       if line.startswith('>'):
           current = line.strip()
           counts[current] = 0
       else:
           counts[current] += 1
```

then simply loop and print the counts:

```
for entry, count in counts.items():
    print('{} {:2d}'.format(entry, count))
```

You could even just print the number every time you find a new section:

```
count = 0
current = None

with open(filename) as fo:
   for line in fo:
       if line.startswith('>'):
           if current and count:
               print('{} {:2d}'.format(entry, count))
           current = line.strip()
           counts = 0
       else:
           count += 1
   if current and count:
       print('{} {:2d}'.format(entry, count))
```

but you cannot then easily re-purpose the counts for other work.

Comment: I think an ordereddict would be better

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: if the order *matters*, then yes. I doubt it does however.

Answer (score 0):

In one line, just to show that we can:

```
s=""">P136
FCF#0.73
FCF#0.66
FCF#0.86
>P129
FCF#0.72
>P142
>P144
>P134
FCF#0.70
FCF#0.82
"""
```

First variant:

```
print [(i.split("\n")[0],len(i.split("\n")[1:])-1) for i in s.split(">")if i if len(i.split("\n")[1:])-1>0]
```

using re:

```
import re
print [ (block.split("\n")[0],sum(1 for m in re.finditer("#", block)))for block in s.split(">")]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution that attempts to be minimalistic.

```
with open(filename) as f:
    def printcc(current, count):
        if current is not None and count > 0:
            print(current.strip(), count)
    current = None
    count = 0
    for line in f:
        if line[0] == '>':
            printcc(current, count)
            current = line
            count = 0
        else:
            count += 1
    printcc(current, count)
```

In case you actually want all lines that *contain* a `>` character, use `'>' in line` as your condition. If you're targeting Python 2.x, use `print current.strip(), count` because having the outer parentheses will print a two-tuple.